# Excel - Create chart based on Count of Text in a column

Tags: excel, graph, charts

In Excel, I have a sheet showing business name, state, and a 3rd column with either Y or N.  I want to create a bar chart that shows, per state, the COUNT of business with a 'Y'.  I don't care about N.  So I would have a bar chart graph that shows California/84,  Iowa, 21, Oregon, 16, etc.... The only way that I have been able to find to do this is to create a hidden sheet as a copy where I convert Y to 1, and N to 0, then I can do a sum.  Is there any way to graph the COUNT of a text value?  Is there a different way of doing this without having to copy the entire data set?

Answer (score 0):

hmm maybe I suggesting you to use **Apache POI** Implementation [here](https://poi.apache.org/)
Hope it help you at mapping object into excel ! :)

Comment: Pivot charts would be an obvious approach. Any reason why that would not be an option?

Comment: @@Jones - Pivot Charts will let me see that data, but I cannot count the number of occurrences of 'Y'.  I don't want to see the details, just a count.